# Problem overriding scss files in rwd theme

Tags: rwd-theme, rwd

I'm having a strange issue with compass compilation, it seems that even though i have overridden rwd scss files such as /mixin/_typeography.scss, the old copy is still being used for compilation by the @include h2 reference in _product-list.scss, but (correctly) the new copy is being used by _common.scss.

If i go to the mixin folder of the rwd theme and rename _typeography.scss its all fine.

I get the same results with a compass watch batch file or using grunt contrib-watch-sass.

I've tried deleting the sass-cache - no difference.

Config.rb is as follows:

```
require 'susy'

http_path = "/skin/frontend/tpt_rwd/default/"
add_import_path "../../../rwd/default/scss"

css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "../scss"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
fonts_dir = "../fonts"

relative_assets = true
output_style = :compact
environment = :development
```

and grunt config is:

```
options: {
      http_path: 'skin/frontend/tpt_rwd/default/',
      cssDir: 'skin/frontend/tpt_rwd/default/css/',
      sassDir: 'skin/frontend/tpt_rwd/default/scss/',
      imagesPath: 'skin/frontend/tpt_rwd/default/images/',
      javascriptsDir: 'skin/frontend/tpt_rwd/default/js/',
      fontsDir: 'skin/frontend/tpt_rwd/default/fonts/',
      importPath: 'skin/frontend/rwd/default/scss/',
      relativeAssets: true,
      outputStyle: 'compact',
      environment: 'development'
}
```

Obviously this is really holding me up, and really causing me to scratch my head! i know i could just copy all the sass to my theme and remove the import in config, but it seems silly to have to. What am missing\doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you may have some caching issues. Either delete the hidden `.sass-cache` folder manually or run `compass clean` from the command line.

Do you use `compass watch` or do you compile manually?

/edit: sorry, I just re-read your post and saw the compass / grunt edit. If you delete the cache and the problem persists, surely you must have some other problems somewhere. Are there any other hidden files in the scss folder?

Comment: I just tried a manual clean, and it still gives the same output. nothing extra showing in the folders, and even svn commit shows no 'new\extra' files

Comment: Also = i'm trying with both grunt and std compass watch, both show the same behavior. two things that may be relevant, i'm on windows and i use modman so the folders are symbolic links